# how to create static program or process in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, memory-management, process

Just like the functionality provided by static variable of a function in c.
when calling a program multiple time in a bash script, the data of previous  call must be retained to the next call.
Normally when we run a program in bash, it gets terminated after its done.

what i want is when the program is run, it must not terminate by itself and to keep running until kill command is invoked to terminate explicitly.
so that we can keep calling the program to be used in mean time.

Comment: Take a look at [coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html#Coprocesses)

Comment: If you don't want the program to terminate, then don't let it finish.  For example, call a function that will block indefinitely, or at least until some appropriate later time.  There are many possibilities, but [`sigsuspend()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html) is a reasonably good one if used appropriately.  That even works well with your specific choice of using `kill` to stop it.

Comment: There's also static variables for programs and scripts: they're called "files".

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean.  Perhaps you want to implement a daemon that will be long running that you can query multiple times.  Or perhaps you want to use an sqlite database.  Or maybe you just want to generate some data and write it to the filesystem.  What do you mean by "keep calling the program" unless you mean "instantiate new instances of a process"?  Maybe you mean "keep querying the daemon", or "keep reading the files", or "query the database".

Comment: What @WilliamPursell says. What do you mean by "*keep calling the program to be used in the mean time*"? Because calling the program from the shell will spawn a new process. Probably you want to invest effort into making a smarter program rather than shell tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something like this is what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

trap 'echo "No - go away!" >&2' SIGINT
while :; do
    printf '.'
    sleep 5
done

$ ./tst.sh &
[1] 1309
$ ..
$ kill -SIGINT 1309
$ No - go away!
..
$ kill -9 1309
$
[1]+  Killed                  ./tst.sh
```

I'm using the trap just to show that the process is running and can be interacted with until you kill it (with -9 in this case)

Comment: nope, next time you call the same program it must retain the data changes in previous call.

Comment: Then why did you say `what i want is when the program is run, it must not terminate by itself and to keep running until kill command is invoked to terminate explicitly`? That's exactly what my script does and has nothing to do with `next time you call the same program it must retain the data changes in previous call`. Your question is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> when calling a program multiple time in a bash script, the data of previous call must be retained to the next call

These are the solutions I could think of

1. Use a temporary file to store the value.

```
static_var_file=/tmp/static_var
# or use /usr/tmp/static_var to save it between reboots

# load
static_var=$([ -f "$static_var_file ] && cat "$static_var_file" || echo 0)

# the script here
static_var=$((static_var+1))

# save
echo "$static_var" > "$static_var_file"
```

2. Use self modifying script

```
static_var=0  # MARK

# the script here
static_var=$((static_var+1))

# self modify ourselves to store new value
sed '/^static_var=.* # MARK$/s/.*/static_var="'"$static_var"'" # MARK/' "$0"
```

Comment: i want the data to retained on RAM, not on secondary storage.

Comment: Then `mount -o tmpfs tmpfs /yourdir` and use that mountpoint. On most/some systems `/tmp` is mounted to `tmpfs` anyway, so it's RAM. It's linux - everythings a file. To be sure - I think you could use /dev/shm